# Photon Voice Mute/Unmute - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I want to mute/unmute myself with Photon Voice in Unity game engine. How can I do it with coding ?
I tried setting the audio listener volume to zero when pressing the button , but that would only mute others plus any audio sound ( like shooting sound , music etc..)  which I don't want

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mute the mic, then you can add a Recorder component and get it from the code as below.

```
recorder = player.GetComponent<Recorder>();
```

Then using following way you can mute and unmute the mic.

```
recorder.TransmitEnabled = true; //unmute
recorder.TransmitEnabled = false; //mute
```

If you want to mute/unmute speakers then, you should set the volume to 0f/1f of all other players speaker component attached audios sources by iterating each player.
For more information refer to the main documentation from [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/voice/current/getting-started/voice-intro).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check the DemoVoicePun-Scene.

Just simply go to the UI object in the hierarchy, and you can learn from the attached script to that object (i.e. Voice Demo UI).

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ZAf.png) To Mute/Unmute yourself you can use the Recording Enabled property of the Recorder Component.